# Google Place API - autocomplete - how to populate ZIP-code in field?

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

All fields are working fine except the zip code. I've integrated script with Formidable Forms (wordpress plugin). Script seems to work for other fields but postal_code has issues. Can someone look into the code and guide how to resolve this issue
 You can view form here: https://connecteddesigns.org/marco/texas 
Script Source: https://gist.github.com/VanLuda/b2b6fe9047bbf57d5092092b4efc7c98

```
<script>
      // This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
      // of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

      var placeSearch, autocomplete;
      var componentForm = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'long_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
        country: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name'
      };

      function initAutocomplete() {
        // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
        // location types.
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('field_autocomplete')),
            {
            types: ['geocode'],
            componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'}//Country Abbreviation
            });

        // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
        // fields in the form.
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
      }

      function fillInAddress() {
        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        // Get each component of the address from the place details
        // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
          var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
          if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            document.getElementById('field_' + addressType).value = val;
          }
        }
      }

      // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
      // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
      function geolocate() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var geolocation = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
              center: geolocation,
              radius: position.coords.accuracy
            });
            autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
          });
        }
      }
    </script>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEYHERE&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

Comment: Can you console.log `place.address_components` in your function `fillInAddress` and display the results here please.

Comment: @slashroot Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')
Uncaught ReferenceError: place is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it similarly to that and seems to work for me. Have a look at the few changes here

```
var componentForm = {
    'street_number': 'short_name',
    'route': 'long_name',
    'locality': 'long_name',
    'administrative_area_level_1': 'short_name',
    'country': 'long_name',
    'postal_code': 'short_name'
};

function initAutocomplete() {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
    // location types.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById('field_autocomplete')),
        {
            types: ['geocode']
        }
    );

    // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
    // fields in the form.
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
    //restrict the country
    autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({'country': 'US'});
}
```

I set the country restriction after the addListener instead of when the autocomplete element is rendered. As well as passing CAPITAL country code

Comment: Thank you for the response. That didn't seem to work for me. :( Like you mentioned, i moved country restriction after addListener as well as caped US.

Comment: @UmaisBinSajjad have you also updated your `componentForm` to the same as mine? And in function `fillInAddress` after the line `var place = autocomplete.getPlace();` if you do `console.log(place.address_components)` what is being displayed. (It shouldnt be giving you an error since ive tested your form on the website you linked and the fields city and state are being populated)

Comment: Thanks! Yes I have updated `componentForm` . City and state are working as they are suppose to but zip is not. I'm replicating this site as reference and their form's zip code field works. (https://sell.fasthomeoffer.com/get-cash-offer/ ) These are the errors in console:

You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Lu')
870 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')

Comment: Yea i see those console errors as well. But have you added the line i mentioned `console.log(place.address_components)` so we can see the results being returned since its obviously working for 2 fields out of the 3.

Comment: The autofill just doesn't work when i add `console.log(place.address_components)` in function.

Comment: @UmaisBinSajjad Sorry, theres not much more i can do without being able to view whats being printed. Its odd because i use very similar if the the same code for mine and it works just fine. And im surprised that `console.log` makes the autofill not work anymore. And without the content of `place.address_components` itll be hard to determine what the next step should be.

Comment: Thank you @slashroot for all your responses on thread. I'll keep troubleshooting and figure something out. :)